# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided)

Tags: paypal, backend

I am getting error "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided)." while cancelling order from Magento admin. Why I am getting this error and how to solve it.

Comment: I found the issue, The error displayed in case the order is already voided from PayPal, while Magneto is trying the void transaction again. I modified the code to skip  the error #10600 and only show the warning.

Answer (score 3):

If a buyer using PayPal contacts you to cancel an order, or you wish to cancel an order, you can void the authorization. Voiding the authorization will free up any funds reserved for the transaction in PayPal.

Note: Once voided, the transaction buttons disappear from the PayPal Transaction Control panel. You will no longer be able to capture, refund, or reauthorize an order once the authorization has been voided. If you inadvertently void an authorization, you will need to contact the buyer to replace the order, or arrange an alternate payment method. If you already captured funds, you will have to perform a refund.

To void an authorization:

```
From the Store Manager, click the Orders link.
View the order for which you wish to void an authorization.
(The individual order review page will display a PayPal Transaction Control panel for orders where PayPal was the payment method).
```

[image]

```
3. Click the Void Transaction button.
```

The transaction will be processed and the status displayed for you on a confirmation screen. If successful, the transaction will be marked "OK", and after clicking OK to return to the Order Review page, you will see "Voided" in the Payment section of the page.

Comment: The issue is I can't void the payment from the Magento Backend. The payment is only authorized not captured.

Comment: Try this link:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7/voiding-orders-via-backend

Comment: Or this is the probable answer that could help:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7846/capture-void-refund-not-showed-in-magento-admin-area

Comment: I found the issue, The error displayed in case the order is already voided from PayPal, while Magneto is trying the void transaction again. I modified the code to skip  the error #10600 and only show the warning.

Comment: Anyone help me, after void the order from PayPal why i can't cancel the order from magento.